# Install macOS High Sierra won't Delete

Tags: macos, high-sierra

I am kinda running out of room on my Mac, and in System Information (comes up when I click "manage" in "storage" of "About This Mac"), I saw that "Install macOS High Sierra" was taking 5.21 GB.

I thought that deleting it would solve my storage problem for now. I had it because I recently updated my mac to macOS Mojave 10.14 which I love, but that dang file won't go away. I click it, then delete. Then, I get a confirmation, "are you sure" and such.

After clicking "delete" I enter my password for permission because its an "application change". Then, the top tab goes away and nothing happens. I've been thought this process a few dozen times and I have no idea why nothing happens.

How can I get rid of the file and reclaim the space?

It’s in `/Applications` but has a slashed circle symbol over it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Can you open `/Applications` directory and see if it contains a file named "Install macOS High Sierra.app"?

Comment: Yes, it is there. It does however have a slashed circle symbol over it. What does that mean?

Comment: In macOS, that symbol over an app icon means that it won't run when executed (could be due to variety of reasons).

Answer (score 2):

Had this issue for a while and stumbled on the solution this morning.

1. Open Applications folder in Finder
2. Right Click 'Install macOS *****'
3. Click on "Show Package Contents"
4. Click and Drag Contents folder to Trash
5. Empty Trash
6. Click and Drag the Application to Trash
7. Empty Trash

All Gone!